# How do I pass additional exception data to a global exception filter in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a WebAPI 2 project and I've implemented a global error filter attribute which looks like this:

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute: ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecuteContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is MyException)
        {
             // Handle MyException
        }
        else if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            // Handle UnauthorizedAccessException
        }
    }
}
```

When I make calls to an external API and get error responses back I throw `MyException`.

```
var httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.GetAsync(request).Result;
if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var message = "Error calling external API";
    var except = new MyException(message);
    throw except;
}
```

I want to pass the status code that the API returned to the global error filter as part of `MyException`. My first attempt was to add the status code as a property of `MyException`.

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode statusCode;
    public MyException() : base() { }
    public MyException(string message, HttpStatusCode statusCode) : base(message)
    {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

And in the exception throwing:

```
var httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.GetAsync(request).Result;
if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var message = "Error calling external API";
    var except = new MyException(message, httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);
    throw except;
}
```

Then in my filter I was casting `context.Exception` back to a `MyException` and trying to access the property, but the property always came back as `null`.

```
var ex = context.Exception as MyException;
var code = ex.statusCode; // Always comes back as null
```

My second attempt was to add the status code to the `Data` property that `MyException` inherits from `Exception`.

```
var httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.GetAsync(request).Result;
if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var message = "Error calling external API";
    var except = new MyException(message);
    except.Data.add("status", httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);
    throw except;
}
```

However, when I tried to access it in the filter, `Data` had no keys. I know that I could include the status code in my exception message and then parse it out in the filter, but I would rather not do that because I think it's the wrong solution. How can I get the status code to my exception filter so that I can use it when handling my exceptions?

Comment: if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) {     var message = "Error calling external API";     var except = new MyException(message);     throw except; } in this code where are you passing status code ?

Comment: The two attempts that I mention are inserted before `throw except`.

Comment: @Kris I added the calls I was making to make it more clear exactly how I was trying to pass the status code

Comment: Do the StatusCode and Data properties have the correct value **before** you throw the exception?

Comment: @PoByBolek Yes. Both have the correct data before I throw the exception.

Comment: Is it possible that the exception is being wrapped somewhere else and your exception is actually an inner exception in there?

Comment: @JohnKoerner That's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception may be getting wrapped higher up in the call stack. It will then be in an inner exception.  You could iterate all of the inner exceptions to see if any of them are your exception, but your code to access the properties should work as expected.

```
        var ex = context.Exception;
        while (ex != null)
        {
            if (ex is MyException)
            {
                // Do work
                break;
            }

            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
```